# Error installing pyproj

Tags: python, pyproj, pip

I am getting the following error when attempting to install geopandas:

```
[~]$ pip3.9 install pyproj
Collecting pyproj
  Using cached pyproj-3.6.0.tar.gz (224 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [22 lines of output]
      <string>:10: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-r0vx9y7v/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-r0vx9y7v/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-r0vx9y7v/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 229, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 168, in get_extension_modules
        File "<string>", line 25, in get_proj_version
        File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
          return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
        File "/usr/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '/usr/local/bin/proj' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
[~]$
```

This is what I get if I just run proj (just seeing that it runs):

```
[~]$ /usr/local/bin/proj
Usage: proj [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

  proj is a tool for managing many different projects, and archiving projects
  that you're no longer actively working on.

  It assumes you have a working folder containing active projects, and an
  archive folder with inactive projects. proj helps organise inactive projects
  by year and by quarter (e.g. 2013/q3/my-project).

  proj needs an archive directory specified by the PROJ_ARCHIVE environment
  variable.

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  archive  Move an active project to the archive.
  list     List the contents of the archive directory.
  restore  Restore a project from the archive into the current directory.
[~]$
```

What do you think causing the pyproj install to fail?

[Updated 19 September, 2023 to add the following.]

Here's the content of /usr/local/bin/proj:

```
[~]$ cat /usr/local/bin/proj
#!/usr/bin/python3.9.exe
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from proj import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
[~]$
```

Comment: What platform/arch? There are several [built distributions](https://pypi.org/project/pyproj/3.6.0/#files), but a few are missing and could be requested, e.g. for Alpine. The `/usr/local/bin/proj` command appears to be some project management tool, and is not [`proj`](https://proj.org/en/9.3/apps/proj.html)

Comment: I'm on CYGWIN, 64 bit, Windows 10 Home.  

Comment: I added the content of /usr/local/bin/proj above.

Comment: Oh, you must have installed unrelated [proj](https://pypi.org/project/proj/). First remove that, and install [PROJ](https://proj.org/en/9.3/download.html) instead. Looks like [this](https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/proj-src.html) and [this](https://www.cygwin.com/packages/summary/libproj-devel.html) could be installed to help.